# What is needed to create a new LDAP database?

Tags: ldap

I'm trying to create a small LDAP in a directory of ldap/slapdCollection. Here is what I have so far.

```
dn: dc=slapd-Collection,dc=info
o: info 
description: Root Entry for test ldap 
objectClass: top 
objectClass: dcObject 
objectClass: organization

dn: ou=People,dc=slapd-Collection,dc=info 
ou: People description: All users 
objectClass: top 
objectClass: organizationalUnit
dn: ou=SuperUsers,dc=slapd-Collection,dc=info 
ou: SuperUsers 
description: Special Users 
objectClass: top 
objectClass: organizationalUnit

dn: ou=Companies,dc=slapd-Collection,dc=info 
ou: Companies description: All test companies 
objectClass: top 
objectClass: organizationalUnit
```

The command I'm using to insert these values while creating the directory manager is failing, both with a password provided as well as with a password file `ldapadd -D "cn=Directory Manager,dc=slapd-Collection,dc=info" -p [redacted] -f create.ldif`.

Regardless of whether or not I provide a password in the command itself or at the prompt using this command, I seem to be missing something somewhere, as every attempt to create this simple database is being met with the message `ldap_simple_bind: Can't connect to the Ldap server - Connection refused`. The host is the current server, and I'm in the current directory of `slapd-Collection` (where I want the files to be). What needs to be changed to get this small database up and running?

Comment: You have not specified what LDAP directory software you're using, eg OpenLDAP.